# fopen in C wont create file

Tags: c

```
FILE * f = fopen("c:\\out.txt", "wb");
if(f == NULL)
     printf("ERR");
```

This code prints ERR.  c:\out.txt does not yet exist.  However if I create an empty file called out.txt and then place in the c:\ the code executes fine.  How do I make c create a file if it does not exist?

Comment: Run your program as Administrator. You probably don't have permissions to create files at c:\\

Comment: could you try `w+` instead of `wb`. you could also try calling fclose. at the end of the program.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what w+ does?

Comment: @KirillKulakov: It's not clear how either of those would help here...

Comment: Print out the value of `errno` when `fopen` fails to determine what the problem is.

Comment: @KirillKulakov: According to the doc for "w" access mode: "Action if file does not exist: create new" - so it has nothing to do with access mode.

Comment: You are lucky and not a danger seeker using an account with admin-rights, so you may not write to the root of your machine C-drive. Use a different path to the file you want to create. Try `.\\out.txt` for example.

Comment: Why not print out `errno` to find out why? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/

Comment: @Qiu Good to know, anyway I thought that the file was created when closed.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by running Netbeans with administrator privileges.  This caused the exe to also be run as administrator so now I can write to c:.